# Extract time from datetime using moment.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

my datetime format is given below.

```
var datetime =Wed Apr 8 15:05:00 UTC+0530 2015;
```

I only want to get the time `15.05`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `format()` and specify the desired token.

`moment().format('HH.mm')`.

Docs for tokens can be found [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create moment object from your string. Then append .format()

```
var date = moment("Wed Apr 8 15:05:00 UTC+0530 2015").format('HH.mm');
alert(date);
var date = moment("Wed Apr 8 15:05:00 2015").format('HH.mm');
alert(date);
```

If you want to get "15.05", you will need to remove the "UTC+0530", because its modifying your time :)
You can see examples here:
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/